# Why is there independence in this proof of the existence of a countable sequence of iids?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, independence

Consider this

> **Proposition 2.4.1.** Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be the probability space of Lebesgue measure on the Borel subsets of $(0,1)$. Let $(F_n: n \in \mathbb{N})$ be a sequence of distribution functions. Then there exists a sequence $(X_n: n \in \mathbb{N})$ of independent random variables on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ such that $X_n$ has distribution function $F_{X_n}=F_n$ for all $n$.

> **Proof:**  Choose a bijection $m: \mathbb{N}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ and set $Y_{k, n}=R_{m(k, n)}$, where $R_m$ is the $m$th Rademacher function. Set
> $$Y_n=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 2^{-k} Y_{k, n} . $$
> Then $Y_1, Y_2, \ldots$ are independent and, for all $n$, for $i 2^{-k}=0 . y_1 \ldots y_k$, we have
> $$ \mathbb{P}(i 2^{-k}<Y_n \leq(i+1) 2^{-k})=\mathbb{P}(Y_{1, n}=y_1, \ldots, Y_{k, n}=y_k)=2^{-k} $$
> so $\mathbb{P}(Y_n \leq x)=x$ for all $x \in[0,1]$. Set
> $$ G_n(y)=\inf \{x: y \leq F_n(x)\} $$
> then, by Lemma 2.2.1, $G_n$ is Borel and $G_n(y) \leq x$ if and only if $y \leq F_n(x)$. So, if we set $X_n=G_n(Y_n)$, then $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ are independent random variables on $\Omega$ and
> $$ \mathbb{P}(X_n \leq x)=\mathbb{P}(G_n(Y_n) \leq x)=\mathbb{P}(Y_n \leq F_n(x))=F_n(x) . $$

**Question:** I am struggling to see why are $Y_n$ independent. I can see why this would be true if the sums were finite as independence would follow from the fact that the Rademacher functions are independent and then talk about finite intersections. However, I do not see how one argues for the independence of the infinite sums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n\geq 0$, you can show that
$$
S^{n}_N:=\sum_{k=1}^{N}2^{-k} Y_{k, n}
$$
converges almost, surely. Its limit is $Y_n$, this even this way that $Y_n$ is defined. Now, take two bounded measurable functions $f$ and $g$, by Lebesgue theorem
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[f(Y_{1})g(Y_2)\right]=\lim\limits_{N\to \infty}\mathbb{E}\left[f(S^{1}_N)g(S^2_N)\right].
$$
However, you seem to agree that $S^{1}_N$ and $S^{2}_N$ are independent (as finite sums of independent random variables). Hence,
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[f(Y_{1})g(Y_2)\right]=\lim\limits_{N\to \infty}\mathbb{E}\left[f(S^{1}_N)g(S^2_N)\right]=\lim\limits_{N\to \infty}\mathbb{E}\left[f(S^{1}_N)\right]\mathbb{E}\left[g(S^2_N)\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[f(Y_1)\right]\mathbb{E}\left[Y_2\right],
$$
where the last equality follows again from Lebesgue theorem. You can extend this to show the independence of the whole family $(Y_n)_n$.

Comment: Hi, do you mean that we can take f and g to be indicator functions and then get independence?

Comment: Well, that was one of my concerned. I didn't know what definitions/criterias you are used to.  Having $\mathbb{E}\left[g(X)f(Y)\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[g(X)\right]\mathbb{E}\left[f(Y)\right]$ for all bounded measurable function is equivalent to independence (It can be taken as definition). Anyway, you can indeed take $f$ and $g$ as indicator functions to recover a definition based on the events.

Answer (score 0):

I think I recognise these notes :)

You're right that's there's a bit of an oversight in that this hasn't been justified fully. I think to some extent it's just meant to be a quick remark, and the author intends it to be obvious that $Y_n$ are all independent. This is because $Y_n$ depends only on $Y_{k,n}$ for $k \in \Bbb N$, so each $Y_n$ depends on a different set of random variables, which are all independent. More formally,
$\sigma(Y_n) \subseteq \sigma(Y_{1,n}, Y_{2,n}, \dotsc) =: \mathcal F_n$, and it should be believable that these $\sigma$-algebras are independent. This fact holds in great generality, and in particular you really shouldn't think of this as a consequence of the dominated convergence theorem.

We can show the $\mathcal F_n$ are independent by using a similar argument to eg the argument at the start of the proof of Kolmogorov's zero-one law.

We need to show that for any $N$, $\{\mathcal F_1, \dotsc, \mathcal F_N\}$ are independent. However, we may actually just as well assume that $N = 2$.

(Then we will be done, by induction on $N$ - because $\mathcal F_2, \dotsc, \mathcal F_N$ all together still just depend on some countable sequence of independent random variables. In particular if $A_i \in \mathcal F_i$, then $A_2 \cap \dotsc \cap A_N$ is an event in $\sigma(Y_{k,n} : n \ge 2, k \in \Bbb N)$. So by applying the case $N = 2$, we may write
$\Bbb P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap \dotsc A_N)
 = \Bbb P(A_1) \Bbb P(A_2 \cap \dotsc \cap A_N)$ and then finish using the inductive hypothesis.)

But indeed, $\mathcal F_i$ is generated by the $\pi$-system $\mathcal A_i$ of events of the form
$\{Y_{1,i} \in B_1, Y_{2,i} \in B_2, \dotsc, Y_{k,i} \in B_k\}$ for $k \in \Bbb N$ and $B_j$ measurable in the target space. It should be clear that the $\pi$-systems $\mathcal A_1$ and $\mathcal A_2$ are independent. So by the "$\pi$-system independence lemma" (Theorem 1.12.1 in Norris' notes), $\mathcal F_1$ and $\mathcal F_2$ are independent. So we are done.

This proof is quite similar to the nicest way I know to prove that finite sums of disjoint sets of independent random variables are independent. I wonder what argument you had in mind for that?

Note that the fact right at the start ($\sigma(Y_n) \subseteq \mathcal F_n$) does make use of some facts about sums and limits of measurable functions. They're mostly fairly straightforward. You should be able to prove that if you can solve problem 2.1 [here](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/study/II/Probability%2BMeasure/2022-2023/ex1.pdf).